# About Changing Display Strings at Runtime to Modify the Location of Nodes in Simulation

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

In a planar simulation scenario, I can modify the position of nodes by using getDisplayString() ->setTagArg.

```
 cModule* parents = getParentModule();  //找到应用层app是UdpSink的节点
    auto dispStr = parents->getDisplayString();  //显示字符串
    std::cout<<dispStr<<std::endl;
    double x_coord = atof(dispStr.getTagArg("p", 0));
    double y_coord=  atof(dispStr.getTagArg("p", 1));
    double z_coord=  atof(dispStr.getTagArg("p", 2));
    //更新移动节点的位置
    dispStr.setTagArg("p", 0, std::to_string(x).c_str());
    dispStr.setTagArg("p", 1, std::to_string(y).c_str());
    dispStr.setTagArg("p", 2, std::to_string(z).c_str());
    parents->setDisplayString(dispStr.str());
    std::cout<<x_coord<<std::endl;
```

"However, my simulation requires a 3D scene, so I modeled the example of showcases/mobility/spatial and set the scene of" Integrated OsgVisualizer "under OSG, but I printed the display string of the node."

```
auto dispStr = parents->getDisplayString();  // display string
std::cout<<dispStr<<std::endl;
```

It appears to have no p attribute. Is it like this? Therefore, I cannot update the node position in a 3D scene in this way now. If I want to continue through this method, what should I do. I hope to receive your advice and help. Thank you

Comment: Tagging this as `omnet++` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I have the OMNeT++tag displayed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the tag that you require using `insertTag()`, for example:

```
cModule* parents = getParentModule();
auto &dispStr = parents->getDisplayString();
dispStr.insertTag("p");
dispStr.setTagArg("p", 0, x); // x is int
dispStr.setTagArg("p", 1, y);
```

Notes:

- `setTagArg()` may take a long number as an argument
- `p[2]` represents [an arrangement of submodule vectors](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:display-strings:module-and-connection-display-strings), not z index

Comment: "I checked the hyperlink you provided, and I understand what I did wrong -->p [2].". If you add a tag through insertTag(), how can you use this tag to represent the z position. P [0] indicates x, which is defined dead from the beginning in the OMNeT++simulator. What if I want to add a label p [6] to indicate its position on the z-axis. I hope to receive your help. Thank you again

Comment: p[6] is not used by OMNeT++ so you can assume that it represents z. Fill free to set it using `setTagArg("p", 6, z)` and read using `getTagArg("p", 6)`.

Comment: Adding a p [6] tag is a simple matter. However, the meaning of p [0] is X position of the center of the icon/shape; Defaults to automatic graph layout, which is specified in advance in OMNeT++. Therefore, I can modify the value of p [0] through setTagArg to achieve movement in the x direction. "I cannot specify the meaning (position on the z-axis) of a new label p [6], so I cannot modify the value of p [6] in the z-direction through setTagArg, which is my confusion."

Comment: In the question you have asked how to change `displayString` at runtime and I answered you. If that problem was resolved could you be so kind and mark the answer as accepted? It helps others find the solution for similar problem. And if you have further doubts, ask a new question providing [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I have marked accepted. I will raise a new question for my doubts. I look forward to your help. Thank you again